# How to upload multiple images to sanity.io?

Tags: javascript, sanity

I am searching for a way to uploading multiple images to sanity.io. Only thing that I found is [this issue](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/1547).

But maybe there is another way. Some npm-plugin or node.js app approach.

I'll be grateful for the help.

Comment: have the same issue

Comment: I'm still curious to learn if there's a way to do bulk images now

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer in sanity.io slack. [This is it](https://sanity-io-land.slack.com/archives/C9Z7RC3V1/p1580236905456600?thread_ts=1580236241.455100&cid=C9Z7RC3V1).

For multiple images upload you have to use array of images instead of field with 'image' type

```
{
 name: 'imagesGallery',
 title: 'Images gallery',
 type: 'array',
 of: [{ type: 'image' }]
}
```

This is simple and elegant way to solve my problem. Excellent!

Comment: Not a fan of this, as let's say you have a gallery and wish to give the client the ability to upload loads of images at once, rather than being able to select a bunch of them in the image gallery, they have to do them one by one and that's really tedious.